# How to write a tricky update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to update a table and set a column (enabled) to 1 with the following rules

1. There must be 1 (and never 0 or > 1) record with enabled set to 1 per Employee_Guid.
2. It should choose the record that has deleted set to 0 (there should only be one or no records with deleted set to 0 per Employee_Guid) to set enabled to 1.
3. If all records have deleted set to 1 it should use the record with the most recent Create_Date_Time
4. If there is a tie with the create date time any record of the tieing group can be set to 1 but only one of them can be used.

If there are more than 1 record with deleted set to 0 I would like a error thrown as that is a illegal state.

Here is what I have so far

```
if(exists(select count(employee_guid) from Employees_M where deleted = 0 group by employee_guid having count(employee_guid) > 1))
    RAISERROR('More than one record has deleted set to 0')
Update Employees_M set [ENABLE] = 0

select * into #t from employees_m where deleted = 0
insert into #t select * from employees_m where employee_guid not in (select employee_guid from #t) 
                                         and --fulfill rules 3 and 4

Update Employees_M set [ENABLE] = 1
where pk_guid in (select pk_guid from #t)
```

Here is the table structure

```
PK_Guid (primary key, uniuque, uniuqueidenitfier, not null)
Employee_Guid (uniuqueidenitfier, not null)    
Deleted (bit, not null)
Enable (bit, not null)
Create_Date_Time (datetime defaults to getdate(), not null)
```

This is not just a "Show me teh codez" question. I want to learn how to do it correctly, so links or examples that are similar but not solving the problem would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often possible to use `row_number` in this scenario.  Its `order by` clause allows you to assign priorities.  In your case, `deleted asc` and `Create_Date desc` would seem to capture the requirements.

Here's an example of how to use `row_number` in an update query:

```
update  emp
set     enabled = case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by employee_guid 
                                   order by deleted, Create_Date desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    @employees
        ) emp
```

[Full example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/105101/)

Comment: I have never seen SE Data before. That thing is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hard question. Try this, I hope this works.

```
if(exists(select 1 from Employees_M where deleted = 0  having count(employee_guid) > 1))
    RAISERROR('More than one record has deleted set to 0')

Update Employees_M E
set [ENABLE] = 1
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Employees_M  
  WHERE E.employee_guid = employee_guid 
  AND (DELETED = 0 OR DELETED IS NULL)
) --SECOND POINT
OR EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Employees_M  
  WHERE E.employee_guid = employee_guid 
  AND ENABLE <> 1 -- 4 POINT 
  AND Create_Date_Time =  
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT(MAX(Create_Date_Time)) 
    FROM Employees_M 
    WHERE E.employee_guid = employee_guid 
  )
  HAVING COUNT(employee_guid) = SUM(deleted) --3 POINT
)
```